# SVG animate has no method

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-animate, transform

I have an SVG (html):

```
    <div>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <g id="radius-selector">
          <!-- Circle -->
          <circle id="radius-circle" cx="50%" cy="35%" r="25%" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
          <!-- Radius ring -->
          <circle id="radius-ring" cx="50%" cy="35%" r="12.5%" stroke="green" stroke-width="10" fill="none"/>
        </g>

      </svg>
    </div>
```

I am trying to transform the SVG, using JQuery to select it like this :

```
$('#radius-ring')[0].animate({fill: "#223fa3", stroke: "#000", "stroke-width": 80, "stroke-opacity": 0.5}, 2000);
```

but I keep getting the error in the console:

```
TypeError: Object #<SVGCircleElement> has no method 'animate'
arguments: Array[2]
get message: function () { [native code] }
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set message: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: "undefined_method"
__proto__: Error
```

Do I need to actually install a plugin or library to animate the SVG?   I thought that you can achieve this?  If so I would appreciate a point in the right direction....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you are using `DOM` object not `jquery` object. Try this way

```
 $('#radius-ring').animate({fill: "#223fa3", stroke: "#000", "stroke-width": 80, "stroke-opacity": 0.5}, 2000);
```

instead of

```
 $('#radius-ring')[0].animate({fill: "#223fa3", stroke: "#000", "stroke-width": 80, "stroke-opacity": 0.5}, 2000);
```

Comment: I need to animate the stroke-width, first i try without quotes. Thanks to you I have seen that quotes are necessary .